# Can we have a high-speed low-drag close vote review queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, vote-to-close

I almost never use the review queue.  I mean, look at this big dumb thing

> [image: omg f this]

It lumbers along, slowly plodding through the list of questions with close votes, one by one, until I die from boredom.  It's slow, inefficient, and wastes what little time I have to help close crap.

**What I want** is to jump in my *F-15 SCREAMING EAGLE CRAP QUESTION SLAUGHTERING SPEED DEMON*, zoom over the landscape looking for targets of opportunity upon which I can swoop down and strike with my depleted uranium VTC rounds.

It could look like your normal questions list, but only featuring those questions that have active close votes

> [image]

(Wow, Jarrod, I didn't think you were behind those spam posts!)

I can skim through hundreds of questions in minutes, popping open interesting candidates for further review into background tabs.

- "Oh, hell no, we don't recommend web hosting companies!" ***ctrl-click***
- "What moonspeak is this translated from???" ***ctrl-click***
- "Did you just *link* your website in your *title*?" ***ctrl-click***
- "Did you just say *best practice???*" ***ctrl-click***
- "I'll give this guy a Tutorial!" ***ctrl-click***
- "BROTHER PRINTER SUPPORT NUMBER!!!!" ***ctrl-click***

Essentially this is the same workflow I follow when going through the regular list of questions.  I see a question which smells funny, I pop it open in a new tab, and when I get to it I can deal with it as I do any other question.

I find this workflow *so much superior* for finding and dealing with questions that need closin' than the actual review queue.  It's much faster and I get to help quickly do the needful.  Please make it even better by showing me a list of questions with close votes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808198/best-places-to-learn-java-script

Comment: I share the sentiment, which is why I wrote a [Review+](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/review%20-page/nfaaglhemabjbpddkbahiogfclhkablj) extension for Chrome. It takes the 200 newest questions and gives a list of only those with a (i) pending close votes; (ii) downvotes but not too many upvotes; (iii) questions from 1 rep users. Here is [the API request I use](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#page=1&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!Pvy_Gp-8X.RCpincNnWhlAdh0ZN5YY&site=stackoverflow), the rest is just filtering and display.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato I love you, and I want to have your baby.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808457/looking-for-recommendations-on-design-patterns-for-with-lots-of-data

Comment: Re the last one: does spam even belong to the CV queues?

Comment: @JanDvorak why not? Of course, those flags would last a hot second, so it's probably pointless...  It's just a mockup.  Wanted to have the question be one of the PRINTER SUPPORT NUMBER spam posts, so therefore Spam has to be an option.

Comment: A streamlined version of "Review+" is now available [as a web app](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw0e1JgXXH6F1f1R_9ZKNQ5wPNcNOPfK7rNW68ohyWIvf0pDiI/exec); no need to install an extension.

Answer (score 12):

You're almost describing the *old* close review queue. The first one, [the one waffles talks about here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/improved-reviewing/). It was awesome. I mean, it was slow and no one used it, but in theory it was awesome: a list of questions, tons of powerful filters, inline actions.

It suffered from a couple of big flaws:

1. There was no obvious way to say that a question *shouldn't* be closed. So eventually your list was mostly questions you didn't care about closing. This also relates to a fundamental problem with list-interfaces for queues in general: folks tend to cherry-pick until they don't see any cherries, and then go away.
2. It was restricted to 10K users. There was no real guidance or context or auditing or meta-review; it was just a big list of questions, intended for use by folks who already knew what they were doing. Problem is, once you know what you're doing it isn't really that hard to find questions that need to be closed, so the best use for it was finding questions that were *one vote away* from being closed in a particular tag. Which was awesome, but also *really, really slow*. The only reason it didn't crash and burn constantly was that so few people actually used it, which *also* precluded opening it up to users with < 10K.

*If you know what you're doing*, it's actually pretty trivial to write userscripts for this stuff (I know you know this...) - so when I have need of it, I usually just pull a list of question IDs out of SEDE and run through them.

But as a built-in tool, this idea is dead; we already tried it and got nowhere.

Comment: (1) doesn't really apply to SO at present. When you don't see any more cherries...  refresh. And old non-cherries age away. [I'm not disagreeing with the idea being dead.]

Comment: I'm not talking about replacing one with the other, just adding an alternative view on the situation.  Granted, point 1 would still hold.  And there might be an issue where all the juicy close questions get sucked out of the review queue, thus making it even more dry and boring than it is now...

Comment: Any one of the issues afflicting the old queue *could* have been fixed, @HomegrownTomato - fixing all of them wasn't gonna happen though.